# Set time widget?

Tags: android

Could anyone tell me how it's done to make a scroll bar like this? Is it a widget or what's needed to make it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an override of the existing `DatePickerWidget` available in the original SDK.  You can do your own "skinning" to make it look like this, or use someone else's code.